# Connect contact list to Outlook - A way to group contacts by column filtering?

Tags: outlook, contacts, filter

Is there a way to have one contacts list - with a column that divides/filters contacts into groups (say A, B, C) that when you create a view for just Group A and connect to Outlook, it just syncs Group A into a separate contact group and doesn't include Group B or C?

Or do I just have to create separate contact lists for each group?

We aren't allowed to use SharePoint Designer so if there is a solution that will work without it, that would be most appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to store each group in separate list. I mean if you're requested to do this then most likely permissions or policies or audiences on those groups differ, and for future manageability it's better to divide. You can later use content query web part to visually merge those lists at UI level